# Blazor hang when calling a injected async service which in turns call an async service

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor-server-side

I am having an issue with a `Blazor` component that calls an `Async` injected service where the injected service, in turn, calls another Async method.  If I comment out the `inner` async all works fine?

I've tried to remove the inner async call and will work.  I've tried `Task.CompletedTask` and delay to monitor. I find that all the async methods work as designed and data returns to the component, however the Blazor app freezes when rendered.

> Component code:

```cs
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            cntrols = await parser.getFormElementsAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            var x = e.Message;
        }
    }
```

> From Service:

```cs
public async Task<List<FHIRParser>> getFormElementsAsync()
{
    var tmp = await getItemsAsync();
```

- getItemsAsync() calls another Async HTTP request.  Tracing code all works fine until returns back to Component

I receive no exceptions just hangs

Comment: You can take a full dump of the process (using task manager will do) and open the dump in Visual Studio and look at the threads to see where it's blocked.